# Idea about creation of editable library or list of Lightning Salesforce Internal Errors which Salesforce Support refuses to list in Known Issues

Tags: discussion

When I started developing Lightning Applications, I have faced millions of Salesforce Internal Errors.
I spent a lot of time trying to find the culprit of each of them by gack id but this was tough.
Opening a Salesforce Ticket helps in each case either a little or not at all. Usually they don't fix these gacks and don't put it in the list of known issues so other community members can't benefit from my experience.
Since Salesforce support refuses to create a known issue for each such "runtime" gack and it takes a lot of time to create reproducible environment for each of these millions of errors I was thinking of establishing some library or list of Lightning Internal Errors I faced personally with some descriptions and Salesforce internal bug id if it was provided.

I am not sure if SFSE is appropriate place to post such a library. I think it won't be an usual answer because I want to append it each time I face a new Lightning internal gack. Maybe other user would benefit from it also or maybe would like to append it with the gacks they face.

What do you think? Is this a good idea? How should be this organized? Should I just post list of these on my blog?

Comment: I could be wrong on this, but I don't believe you couldn't just, for example, ask a question you already know the answer to and answering it yourself?

Comment: `millions` ?  :-)   Note: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html

Comment: @cropredy there are different gack id for different errors. Also there are some errors different than Internal Salesforce Errors

Comment: @DanJones I could, but doing it multiple times may be quire boring, and was thinking about some centralized place where you can find all of them together

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although this suggestion could be useful; I have done the following:

1. Post a question in SFSE and then answer it myself ...
2. Thus, benefiting the Community ...
3. Especially, if the question title is structured in such a way as to likely be found in a search

Hence, a bad question name would be:

`Gack in Lightning`

A better question name would be:

`Adding <some component name> to Lightning Service Console: Internal Server Error xxx`

and in the body, avoid hyperbole and frustration, state the use case:  starting conditions, steps to reproduce, essential-only code and optional screen shot,  and then answer succinctly.

[Here is a recent example from me](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145738/auto-launched-flow-that-creates-activities-works-in-classic-fails-with-gack-in)

Comment: Funny, I was thinking of that post and contemplated posting an answer that referenced it.

Comment: Ok. I think I will collect of all those in comments to my post here.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142870/salesforce-internal-error-in-lightning-with-gack-id-850054284/146167#146167

Answer (score 0):

I read suggestion about posting a question with answers in SFSE.
So, probably I will do that for each bug.
I already did for three bugs and also made a blog post which I will edit later when I finish working on other internal errors which are not listed in my post now. For now I put those three items in my post

https://patlatus.wordpress.com/2016/10/27/collection-of-lightning-salesforce-internal-errors-which-salesforce-support-refuses-to-list-in-known-issues/

Also I created a private Google Sheet with the content from blog post.
May be I will change later it to public if anyone else would expose interest in having such list available for community and editable.